# Batch rename all files in a directory to basename-sequentialnumber.extention

Tags: bash, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a directory containing .jpg files, currently named `photo-1.jpg`, `photo-2.jpg` etc. There are about 20,000 of these files, sequentially numbered.

Sometimes I delete some of these files, which creates gaps in the file naming convention.

Can you guys help me with a bash script that would sequentially rename all the files in the directory to eliminate the gaps? I have found many posts about renaming files and tried a bunch of things, but can't quite get exactly what I'm looking for.

For example:

```
photo-1.jpg
photo-2.jpg
photo-3.jpg
```

Delete photo-2.jpg

```
photo-1.jpg
photo-3.jpg
```

run script to sequentially rename all files

```
photo-1.jpg
photo-2.jpg
```

done

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can use sort -k and -n option. but why not photo-00001.jpg wouldn't this sort better?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If you use image 7001 often but then delete image 2, your image 7001 will get a new number. I wouldn't like this system. In fact, if my filenames were constantly changing, I'd rather they were just totally random and there'd be no concept of gaps because they wouldn't be nearly contiguous. Name them like `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000.jpg`

Comment: To your point @Mark Setchell, I'm actually not sure I want to do this. I have a single directory containing all my photos, and I add new photos daily, and from time to time delete photos, and I want to have the directory always be up to date with a sequential numbering system. What other solutions might be more elegent than re-naming all the files frequently?

Comment: It's fine. Do as you wish with your files I just fail to see the benefit of a sequential numbering system and would be put off such a system by the fact that my filenames would constantly be changing under my feet. If they are of no significance, and totally irrelevant, they may as well be random IMHO. Don't worry about my petty foibles though, be happy with your stuff the way you like it.

Answer (score 1):

With `find` and `sort`.

First check the output of

```
find directory -type f -name '*.jpg' | sort -nk2 -t-
```

If the output is not what you expected it to be, meaning the order of sorting is not correct, then It might have something to do with your `locale`. Add the `LC_ALL=C` before the sort.

```
find directory -type f -name '*.jpg' | LC_ALL=C sort -nk2 -t-
```

Redirect it to a file so it can be recorded, add a `| tee output.txt` after the `sort`

Add the `LC_ALL=C` before the `sort` in the code below if it is needed.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

counter=1

find directory -type f -name '*.jpg' |
  sort -nk2 -t- | while read -r file; do
  ext=${file##*[0-9]} filename=${file%-*}
  [ ! -e  "$filename-$counter$ext" ] &&
  echo mv -v "$file" "$filename-$counter$ext"
  counter=$((counter+1))
done # 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

- Change the `directory` to the actual name of your directory that contains the files that you need to rename.
- If your `sort` has the `-V` flag/option then that should work too.
- `sort -nk2 -t-` The `-n` means numerically sort. `-k2` means the second field and the `-t-` means the delimiter/separator is a dash `-`, can be written as `-t -`, caveat, if the directory name has a dash `-` as well, sorting failure is expected. Adjust the value of `-k` and it should work.
- `ext=${file##*[0-9]}` is a Parameter Expansion, will remain only the `.jpg`
- `filename=${file%-*}` also a Parameter Expansion, will remain only the `photo` plus the directory name before it.
- `[ ! -e "$filename-$counter$ext" ]` will trigger the `mv` ONLY if the file does not exists.
- If you want some record or log, remove the comment `#` after the `done`
- Remove the echo if you think that the output is correct

Comment: This works for me on a test directory with a handful of files. When I tried it on a directory with 20,000+ files, it stops after 955 file renames...

Comment: It stopped meaning it hangs or it is done renaming the files? Is there an error?

Comment: no error, no hanging - it renames 955 files and then the process exits back to the terminal.

Comment: If there are no errors that means it succeeded, I have tested that code here. You can count how much files are there in the directory before and after you run the script against it, also check what is in the `log.txt`

Comment: thanks for your help/patience. I have a directory with 24,000 files sequentially named "photo-1.jpg, photo-2.jpg" etc. The first file is photo-1.jpg and the last file in the directory is photo-24000.jpg, except there are 1,500 "gaps" in the numbering sequence due to deleted files. When I run your script in that directory, it only renames 955 files before just stopping. Should'nt the script rename 22,500 files (24,000 - 1,500) and I end up with perfectly sequential numbers 1-22,500?

Comment: @alecxs, thank you for that wonderful comment, but the OP already mentioned that (or at least that's how I understood) there are only `photo-[0-9]*.jpg` without subdirectories, also you don't just `cd` in a script without checking if it succeeded.

Comment: If the OP mentioned that there are other `*.jpg` files besides `photo-[0-9]*.jpg` in the directory in question then, `photo-[0-9]*.jpg` can be use instead of just `'*.jpg'`

Comment: Sure, whatever floats your boat, but in the end the desired outcome/result is what matters.

Comment: You seem to have a better view of what the OP, wants, why not add an answer to this question?

Comment: nope, i would have answered if OP would fullfil minimal requirements. just wanted to help overcome why OP claim your code doesn't work (when it clearly does)

Comment: I don't use `xargs` so I can't really say.